# How to choose grub default OS entry without fixing it to a specific kernel version?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I have Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04, and Windows 10 installed on my machine. I want to update the order of entries in the grub menu so that the default (first) entry is Ubutnu 18.04. The solutions available online suggest manually changing the default to a specific entry, with a specific kernel version. However, after kernel update, won't I need to again change the order to put the latest version on top?

I notice I have this kind of "generic" entry (the first entry, called "Ubuntu") which always loads the last kernel version available of Ubuntu 16.04. How can I have an entry with the same behavior for Ubuntu 18.04 and move it to the top? Also, could someone explain how this entry works? I couldn't find anything online about it.

**P.S:** I tried changing the order and saving with Grub-customizer, but it didn't actually change it! Also, it seems to be inconsistent, because in the first entry named "Ubuntu", when I click edit, I find that it has this part "linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-25-generic". So, it seems to be referring to Ubuntu 18.04 kernel, but when I open the same entry from boot menu, it opens Ubuntu 16.04 instead.

Thank you.

Comment: Your system has one active MBR (per drive, bios will control which drive is used), so you must use `grub-customizer` or make changes on the system that owns the MBR.  If it's 16.04, changes made in 18.04 will be unused and vice-versa. Changes made to /boot/grub/grub.cfg will be overwritten on next `update-grub` (including kernel updates), but changes made to /etc/default/grub will not be lost (ie. that's where to make changes, but you need to run `update-grub` to see the changes copied to your grub.cfg file).

Comment: can you show `grep -i "menuentry '" /boot/grub/grub.cfg|sed -r "s|--class .*$||g"|nl -v 0`

Comment: @guiverc Thank you, that explains why grub-customizer had no effect. I will try again from 16.04 and tell you the result. But I still would like to have that generic Ubuntu entry for 18.04 :)

Comment: @nobody here is the output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kfSzF2YFyj/

Comment: you are right something ist messed up. All ubuntu entries point to /dev/sda7 `fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | egrep "Disk /|/dev/" | sed "s#^/dev/#Part /dev/#" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://' | xargs -n1 -IX sudo sh -c "hexdump -v -s 0x80 -n  2 -e '2/1 \"%x\" \"\\n\"' X | xargs -n1 -IY sh -c \"case  \"Y\" in '48b4') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.96 ;; 'aa75' | '5272') echo X: GRUB Legacy ;; '7c3c') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.97 oder v1.98 ;; '020') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.99 ;; *) echo X: Kein GRUB Y ;; esac\"" `

Comment: @guiverc Thank you, that solved it, and I found the generic "Ubuntu 18.04" entry when I used grub-customizer from 16.04.

Comment: You do not have to use Grub-Customizer, but can manually edit 40_custom yourself. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Answer (score 1):

The distribution you booted from when `sudo update-grub` was last run becomes option `1. Ubuntu` on the grub main menu.

When 18.04 isn't the first option, boot into it and run `sudo update-grub` then it becomes the first option.

**Note:** If a system update installs a new kernel then `update-grub` is run as part of the process automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this based on @[guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc) comment:

> Your system has one active MBR (per drive, bios will control which drive is used), so you must use grub-customizer or make changes on the system that owns the MBR. If it's 16.04, changes made in 18.04 will be unused and vice-versa. Changes made to /boot/grub/grub.cfg will be overwritten on next update-grub (including kernel updates), but changes made to /etc/default/grub will not be lost (ie. that's where to make changes, but you need to run update-grub to see the changes copied to your grub.cfg file).

So, using Grub-customizer from Ubuntu 16.04, since it is the system that owns the MBR on my drive, I was able to re-order the entries, and the generic entry "Ubuntu" for Ubuntu 18.04 was already available in the entry list, so I didn't need to choose a specific kernel version.